# Filter orders to a one day period - SpringBoot JPA MYSQL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to retrieve a list of just the orders created from one day ago till today, and I can't manage to find any help about it, tried everything I found already.
Basically I need a getAllOrders(), but with filtered by that time period, one day....
How do I filter it ? I Found tons of tutorials on how to sort them descending or ascending, nothing else.

My order.java:

```
package com.proj.my.model;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityListeners;
import jakarta.persistence.FetchType;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.ToString;

@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "myorder")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"createdAt"}, 
    allowGetters = true)  
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    private User user;


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = ShoppingCart.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    private List<ShoppingCart> cartItems;
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(updatable = false, name = "createdAt")
    private LocalDate createdAt;

    public LocalDate getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(LocalDate createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public Order() {
    }

    public Order(User user, LocalDate createdAt, List<ShoppingCart> cartItems) {
        this.user = user;
        this.cartItems = cartItems;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setCustomer(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public List<ShoppingCart> getCartItems() {
        return cartItems;
    }

    public void setCartItems(List<ShoppingCart> cartItems) {
        this.cartItems = cartItems;
    }
}
```

My orderservice.java

```
package com.proj.my.service;

import com.proj.my.model.Order;
import com.proj.my.model.CloudProduct;
import com.proj.my.model.ShoppingCart;
import com.proj.my.repository.OrderRepository;
import com.proj.my.repository.CloudProductRepository;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class OrderService {

    private OrderRepository orderRepository;
    private CloudProductRepository cloudProductRepository;

    public OrderService(OrderRepository orderRepository, CloudProductRepository cloudProductRepository) {
        this.orderRepository = orderRepository;
        this.cloudProductRepository = cloudProductRepository;
    }

    public Order getOrderDetail(int orderId) {
        Optional<Order> order = this.orderRepository.findById(orderId);
        return order.isPresent() ? order.get() : null;
    }


    /* @Query(value = "from order t where Date BETWEEN :yesterday AND :now")
    public List<Order> getAllBetweenDates(@Param("yesterday")Date yesterday,@Param("now")Date localdate.now){
        private LocalDate yesterday = now.minus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
        return orderRepository.findAll();
    } */
    
   public List<Order> getAllOrderDetail() {
        return orderRepository.findAll();
    }

    public float getCartAmount(List<ShoppingCart> shoppingCartList) {

        float totalCartAmount = 0f;
        float singleCartAmount = 0f;

        for (ShoppingCart cart : shoppingCartList) {

            String cloudProductName = cart.getProductName();
            Optional<CloudProduct> product = cloudProductRepository.findByProductName(cloudProductName);
            if (product.isPresent()) {
                CloudProduct cloudproduct = product.get();
                singleCartAmount = cart.getQuantity() * cloudproduct.getpriceInEuros();
                
                totalCartAmount = totalCartAmount + singleCartAmount;
                cart.setProductId(cloudproduct.getProductId());
                cart.setAmount(singleCartAmount);
                cloudProductRepository.save(cloudproduct);
            }
        }
        return totalCartAmount;
    }

    public Order saveOrder(Order order) {
        return orderRepository.save(order);
    }
}
```

My orderDTO.java

```
package com.proj.my.dto;

import com.proj.my.model.ShoppingCart;

import java.util.List;

public class OrderDTO {

    private List<ShoppingCart> cartItems;
    private String userEmail;
    private String userName;

    public OrderDTO() {
    }

    public OrderDTO(List<ShoppingCart> cartItems, String userEmail, String userName) {
        this.cartItems = cartItems;
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public List<ShoppingCart> getCartItems() {
        return cartItems;
    }

    public void setCartItems(List<ShoppingCart> cartItems) {
        this.cartItems = cartItems;
    }

    public String getuserEmail() {
        return userEmail;
    }

    public void setuserEmail(String userEmail) {
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
    }

    public String getuserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setuserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "OrderDTO{" +
                ", cartItems=" + cartItems +
                ", userEmail='" + userEmail + '\'' +
                ", userName='" + userName + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

My shoppingcart.java

```
package com.proj.my.model;


import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
/*@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
*/
@Entity
public class ShoppingCart {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private Integer productId;

    private String productName;

    private int quantity;
    
    private float amount;

    public ShoppingCart() {
    }

    public ShoppingCart(Integer productId, String productName, int quantity, float amount) {
        this.productId = productId;
        this.productName = productName;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public ShoppingCart(Integer productId, int quantity) {
        this.productId = productId;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public ShoppingCart(String productName, int quantity) {
        this.productName = productName;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(Integer productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public float getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(float amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ShoppingCart{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", productId=" + productId +
                ", productName='" + productName + '\'' +
                ", quantity=" + quantity +
                ", amount=" + amount +
                '}';
    }
}
```

And finally my orderController.java

```
package com.proj.my.controller;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.proj.my.dto.OrderDTO;
import com.proj.my.dto.ResponseOrderDTO;
import com.proj.my.model.Order;
import com.proj.my.model.User;
import com.proj.my.service.CloudProductService;
import com.proj.my.service.OrderService;
import com.proj.my.service.UserService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class OrderController {

    private OrderService orderService;
    private CloudProductService cloudProductService;
    private UserService userService;


    public OrderController(OrderService orderService, CloudProductService cloudProductService, UserService userService) {
        this.orderService = orderService;
        this.cloudProductService = cloudProductService;
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/getOrder/{orderId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Order> getOrderDetails(@PathVariable int orderId) {

        Order order = orderService.getOrderDetail(orderId);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(order);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/getOrder")
    public List<Order> getAllOrderDetails() {
        return orderService.getAllOrderDetail();
    }

    @PostMapping("/placeOrder")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseOrderDTO> placeOrder(@RequestBody OrderDTO orderDTO) {

        ResponseOrderDTO responseOrderDTO = new ResponseOrderDTO();

        float amount = orderService.getCartAmount(orderDTO.getCartItems());

        User user = new User(orderDTO.getuserName(), orderDTO.getuserEmail());
        
        Integer userIdFromDb = userService.isUserPresent(user);

        if (userIdFromDb != null) {
            user.setUserId(userIdFromDb);
        }else{
            user = userService.createUser(user);
        }

        LocalDate createdAt = LocalDate.now(); 

        Order order = new Order(user, createdAt, orderDTO.getCartItems());

        order = orderService.saveOrder(order);

        responseOrderDTO.setAmount(amount);

        responseOrderDTO.setDate(com.proj.my.util.DateUtil.getCurrentDateTime());
        
        responseOrderDTO.setOrderId(order.getId());


        return ResponseEntity.ok(responseOrderDTO);
    }}
```

Comment: Now if only in JPA you could write a query, which you could put on a Spring Data repository method...

Comment: I just can't do a proper query, I tried write one for my soft deletion, and had to go around the solution and write something else

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to use a query? Used it uncountable times... Your problem is you are adding the `@Query` in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

You can add method in `OrderRepository` interface

```
public List<Order> findByCreatedAtBetween(LocalDate d1, LocalDate d2)
```

and call it

```
orderRepository.findByCreatedAtBetween(today.minusDays(1),today);
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details

Comment: Thanks sir, I managed to do it, because of you !! Thanks !